# Is there a way to use {} inside a for-each loop in XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to create a html page using xslt, and now I have encountered a roadblock using the for-each element. The line in question is the following

```
<xsl:for-each select="../../*:subscritores/subscritor[@userID = '{@userID}']/*:video">
```

Does anyone know how I can make the for-each loop run for different users, when the user is clearly marked in earlier part of the code?

If i try to simply print out @userID I get the correct result, meaning it should work as intended.

I tried parsing the xpath and it returned a list of nodes (as inteeded). I also tried brute-forcing it by replacing {@userID} whit a valid userID, and it worked fine, telling me the problem was that part indeed.

The full code is here:

XML - https://pastebin.com/CBhmUPRQ

XSL - https://pastebin.com/Jzb3yG3N

XSL (imported file) - https://pastebin.com/NfVGxwy4

Also, most data are written in Portuguese, and the rest is complete gibberish. If necessary I will gladly translate, whatever you find necessary.

Edit - If necessary, the DTD is here https://pastebin.com/6fHdTset

Comment: Please read: [mcve].

Comment: Hard to tell just from the information in the question (I’m not going to look at the pastebin links), but try changing `'{@userID}'` with `current()/@userID`.

Comment: Curly braces like this are never needed inside an XPath expression. Usually you just want to replace `'{$x}'` by `$x`; but in this case the result would obviously be nonsense, so you have a context problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it seems you have variable elements related by an attribute value and you want to follow cross-references based on the attribute value so the most efficient way in XSLT is to declare keys with `xsl:key` and then use the `key` function to follow the cross-references e.g.

```
<xsl:key name="subscritor-por-id" match="subscritor" use="@userID"/>
<xsl:key name="video-por-id" match="video" use="@videoID"/>
<xsl:key name="comentario-por-user" match="comentario" use="de/@userID"/>
```

then the code (without the include, but it should show the principle approach) becomes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xhtml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:output doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xml:lang="pt">
            <head>
                <title>Pagina Utilizador - Vista Longa</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS.css" charset="UTF-8"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="barra_de_navegacao">
                    <a href="../main.xhtml" class="button1">Pagina Inicial</a>
                    <a href="../listas/videos.html" class="button1">Vídeos</a>
                    <a href="../listas/lista_videos.html" class="button1">Lista de videos</a>
                    <a href="../listas/lista_users.html" class="button1">Lista de utilizadores</a>
                </div>
                <div class="display" id="user">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//user[@userID = 'user001']"/>
                    <!-- Para mudar utilizador, mudar aqui-->
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:key name="subscritor-por-id" match="subscritor" use="@userID"/>
    <xsl:key name="video-por-id" match="video" use="@videoID"/>
    <xsl:key name="comentario-por-user" match="comentario" use="de/@userID"/>

    <xsl:template match="user">
        <xsl:apply-imports/>
        <div class="user_subscricoes">
            <h1>
                <xsl:value-of select="@userID"/>
            </h1>
            <h3>Subscrições</h3>
            <h3>Videos</h3>
            <ul>
                <!-- Comecando em user, precisamos subir na arvore, até á raiz para depois poder descer em direção aos subscritores-->
                <xsl:for-each select="key('subscritor-por-id', @userID)/*:video">
                    <li>
                        <a href="../videos/{@videoID}.xhtml" class="button2">
                            <xsl:value-of select="key('video-por-id', @videoID)/nome"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="user_comentarios">
            <!---->
            <h1>
                <xsl:value-of select="@userID"/>
            </h1>
            <!---->
            <h3>Comentários</h3>
            <ul>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('comentario-por-user', @userID)">
                    <li>
                        <div class="button2">
                            <a href="../Vídeos/socialtube-vid001.xhtml"> <xsl:value-of select="/texto"/></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKxn/1